# C : is there "lazy evaluation" when using && operator, as in C++?

Tags: c, boolean, evaluation

I would like to know if this looks correct :

```
while((next !=NULL) && (strcmp(next->name, some_string) < 0) {
    //some process
}
```

I mean, if next is `NULL`, then the second part of the expression won't be ever tested by the compiler? I have heard that in C++ it's the case (but I'm not even sure of it).

Can someone confirm me that I won't get strange errors on some compilers with that?

Comment: @Sean: Testing doesn't necessarily equal "guaranteed by the standard".

Comment: Incidentally this not always true in C++. The expression: `(next != NULL)` may use an overloaded `!=` operator on whatever type `next` is. That operator may return another type on which `&&` is overloaded. And for overloaded `&&` there is no built-in short-circuiting, so the expression on the RHS will be evaluated regardless of the LHS.

Comment: @pmg: Why is this not lazy evaluation?

Comment: @codymanix: Lazy evaluation is about delaying computation until the point that the results are required.  This is short-circuiting, to avoid undefined behaviour (like deferencing a null pointer).

Comment: Hmmm ... looks like some people call that short-circuiting lazy evaluation ( http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazyEvaluation ). I don't agree: to me lazy evaluation is "get ready to evaluate *something* but don't do it just now"; short-circuiting is "if it's ok do *something* right now, otherwise don't ever do it"

Comment: @oli: By your definition, short circuiting is lazy evaluation, too. Avoiding access to uninitialized values is just a side effect of it which is often used.

Comment: @codymanix: I guess it's a matter of definition.  I agree with pmg's definition...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes `&&` is short circuited and you are using it correctly.
If `next` is `NULL` string compare will never happen.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, in C++ short circuit `and` and `or` operators are available.

[Here](http://c-faq.com/expr/shortcircuit.html)'s a question answered in the C-faq on the subject.

Answer (score 9):

It's definitely the case in both C and C++.

Comment: Correction: It's definitely true in C, so it should be true in C++.

Comment: @ruslik - that's no correction. C++ and C are covered by standards, and this answer is correct about what both standards say (for built-in types in C++)

Answer (score 3):

This will work with lazy evaluation (the second statement not evaluated if the first one is evaluated to "false") unless your compiler is so non-standard compliant it can't even be named a C compiler. Millions lines of code in the field rely on this behavior, so you can think that this behavior is just guaranted.

Comment: it's called short circuit evaluation, [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) is something else