# Conditional execution based on short-circuit logical operation

Tags: c, short-circuiting

As the evaluation of logical operators `&&` and `||` are defined as "short circuit", I am assuming the following two pieces of code are equivalent:

```
p = c || do_something();
```

and

```
if (c) {
   p = true;
}
else {
   p = do_something();
}
```

given `p` and `c` are `bool`, and `do_something()` is a function returning `bool` and **possibly having side effects**. According to the C standard, can one rely on the assumption the snippets are equivalent? In particular, having the first snippet, is it promised that if `c` is true, the function won't be executed, and no side effects of it will take place?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958864/c-is-there-lazy-evaluation-when-using-operator-as-in-c

Comment: That's pretty much what short circuiting is all about. And it is guaranteed by the standards ONLY when the operation is between `bool`. NOT when the operator is overloaded.

Comment: @user3267581 What do you mean by overloaded operator? Are you having *C++* in mind?

Comment: Yes, sorry, didn't notice the question was C specific.

Comment: I believe in C++ it should be possible for an overloaded `||`  be implemented as short circuited as well.. But it's a different question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some search I will answer my question myself referencing the standard:
The [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), section **6.5.14 Logical OR operator** is stating:

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the
>   evaluation of the first operand. If the first operand compares unequal
>   to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

And a similar section about `&&`.
So the answer is yes, the code can be safely considered equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct in your thinking. `c || do_something()` will short-circuit if `c` is `true`, and so will never call `do_something()`.

However, if `c` is `false`, then `do_something()` will be called and its result will be the new value of `p`.