# Is the order of the boolean expressions in if statement fixed?

Tags: c

Is the order of `boolean` expressions in this `if` statement fixed?

```
if(boolean_expression_1 || boolean_expression_2) {

}
```

Is `boolean_expression_1` always evaluated before `boolean_expression_2`?  Is the order of evaluation a standard in `C`?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437095/conditional-execution-based-on-short-circuit-logical-operation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's guaranteed. It's called ["short circuit"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) evaluation.

From C11 draft, *6.5.14 Logical OR operator*:

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, **the || operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation**; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
>   a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
>   operands. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second
>   operand is not evaluated.

(emphasis mine).