# Precedence of C operators

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I am new in programming I have started learning with C. I wanted to learn about the precedence of the operators in the following

```
if ( p == 2 || p % 2 )
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please check [man 1 operator](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/precedence.7.html) & try to understand the meanings of precedence and associativity.

Comment: Read C11 [§6.5 Expressions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5), especially [§6.5.5 Multiplicative operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5), [§6.5.9 Equality operators](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.9), and [§6.5.14 Logical OR operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.14). Note that the sub-sections of §6.5 present the operators in order of precedence, higher precedence before lower precedence. The precedence partly controls how operators and operands are grouped together; it is not, however, the whole story (associativity also matters). Etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here

```
if ( p == 2 || p % 2 )
```

it looks like

```
if( operand1 || operand2)
```

where `operand1` is `p == 2` and `operand2` is `P % 2`. Now the logical OR `||` truth table is

```
operand1  operand2  operand1 || operand2
0         0         0
0         1         1
1         0         1
1         1         1
```

From the above table, it's clear that if the first operand `operand1` result is true **then the result will always true** & second operand `operand2` *doesn't get evaluated*.

`operand1` is ==>

- `p == 2` (lets assume `p` is `2`)
- `2 == 2` results in true hence `operand2` doesn't get evaluated and `if` blocks looks like as

  `if(true) { }`

Lets assume `p` is `3` then `operand1` i.e `2 == 3` is false i.e `operand2` gets evaluated i.e `3%2` i.e `1` that means `if` blocks looks like

```
if(true)
{
}
```

Let's assume `p` is `4` then `operand1` i.e `2 == 4` is false i.e `operand2` gets evaluated i.e `4%2` i.e `0` that means `if` blocks looks like

```
if(false)
{
}
```

Hope the above explanation makes sense to you.

About the associativity and precedence, please look into [manual page of operator](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/precedence.7.html)

Comment: This doesn't talk about precedence and associativity at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That means any non-zero integer value of operand2 will make it it true, Isn't it like this?

Comment: The truth table doesn't enforce the rules — it means that the rules of the language make sense, but that's all.  Other languages have `or` operators that always evaluate both terms — Pascal for one, Fortran (Fortran 77 at any rate) for another. Languages derived from or influenced by C tend to use short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: _That means any non-zero integer value of operand2 will make it it true ?_ Yes non-zero value consider as _true_

Answer (score -1):

Refer [Precedence Of Operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and [Short Circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848858/short-circuit-evaluation-on-c).

- Precedence: Operator precedence determines how the operators and operands are grouped within an expression when there's more than one operator and they have different precedences.
- Associativity: Operator associativity is used when two operators of the same precedence appear in an expression.

Since `||` exists, it is required that the left side of the `||` be evaluated first to decide if the right side of `||` needs to be processed. 
If `p == 2` returns true, `p % 2` will not be evaluated.

Hence `p == 2` will be executed first, followed by `p % 2`(because `%` has higher precedence than `||`).

The result of these 2 will then be evaluated against `||`.

Comment: Not my down-vote, but `p % 2` will not be evaluated first because the `||` operator strictly evaluates its LHS before its RHS (including a sequence point), and it only evaluates the RHS if the LHS is false.  If the LHS is true, there's no need to evaluate the RHS.

Comment: Operator precedence concerns how operators are bound to their arguments (as if by parentheses) not necessarily the order of evaluation. The `||` operator does short-circuit evaluation so if the left-hand side is `true` then the the right-hand side is not evaluated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Is it ok now?