# Evaluating an expression containing logical and increment operators in c

Tags: c, operators

I'm trying really hard to understand how this expression is evaluated in c even though I know the precedence and associativity of operators in c language

```
   int i=-4,j=2,k=0,m;
   m = ++i || ++j && ++k;
```

As far as I know the pre increment operators are evaluated first from left to right the the logical and is then the logical so the I value will be -3 the j value will be 3 the k value will be 1 and for m value its 1 but it seems that I'm mistaken.

I'm studying this for an upcoming exam and ill  appreciate any help.

Comment: `||` and `&&` short circuit... i.e in `true || foo()` and `false && foo()` , `foo` is not called.

Comment: Did you observe anything which makes you think that you are mistaken? Can you provide an [mre] of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that you're possibly missing while trying to understand the logic behind the final values obtained is what is known as [short circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848858/what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-in-c) in C.

A summary of what it is -

> if the first operand of the || operator compares to 1, then the second operand is not evaluated. Likewise, if the first operand of the && operator compares to 0, then the second operand is not evaluated.

Going by the above rules, the unary operation on i (`++i`) returns with 1 and hence the following operands of the `||` statement are essentially ignored. Therefore, the value of all other variables remains unaffected and `m` receives the value `1`.