# Strange loop incrementing behaviour in C

Tags: c, loops

I came across this strange loop behaviour in C. Here is the code:

```
char arr[SIZE];
fgets(arr, SIZE, stdin);
char brr[SIZE];
int i;
for(i=0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++){
    if(arr[i] != ' ') brr[i] = (arr[i] + shift - 'a')%26 + 'a';
    else brr[i] = ' ';
}
brr[i-1] = '\0';
```

The code is for [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). It takes some text from the user and stores it in `arr`, then encodes it by shifting the characters, and this encoded version is put in `brr`. So, if user enters 'car' and shift is 2, brr is 'ect'.

The problem is in the last line. Normally, it should be `brr[i] = '\0'`, but for some reason the loop will increase I once more after the condition is wrong. I have tried different combinations and it seems like the problem is somehow related to fgets.

Also, the problem is not specific to for loop, while behaves exactly the same.

Edit: Thanks for all the answers. I see now that I should have taken '\n' into account.

Comment: This code does not account for the `'\n'` that `fgets()` also puts into the buffer. It attempts to "encipher" the newline character as if it were an alphabetic character.

Comment: You want `brr[i] = '\0'`.   The loop ends when `arr[i] == 0`, and `i` does not increment at that point.

Comment: "_The problem is in the last line_" In fact, the problem is presuming the plaintext is only lowercase alpha and SP. There's no provision for UPPERCASE, punctuation or digits, for instance...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I was trying to point where the problem shows itself, but you are right, I should had put it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> somehow related to fgets.

Always test the return values of input functions.

```
// fgets(arr, SIZE, stdin);
if (fgets(arr, SIZE, stdin)) {
  // process arr[]
  ...
```

> if user enters 'car' and shift is 2,

This is unlikely to only typed `'car'` (3 characters).  Certainly the user typed <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (4 characters) which filled `arr[SIZE]` with `"car\n"`.

Rather than encode the 4 characters with `if(arr[i] != ' ')`, test if `arr[i]` is a letter.  Research [`isalpha()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha).

Code could exit the `for()` loop early if `'\n'` is detected.

```
// for(i=0; arr[i] != '\0'; i++){
for(i=0; arr[i] != '\0' && arr[i] != '\n'; i++){
  ...
}
// brr[i-1] = '\0';
brr[i] = '\0';
```

**Advanced**

`brr[i-1] = '\0';` is certainly a problem if `i==0`, possible if the first character read is a *null character*.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. 'isalpha()' is also a really necessary part. But advanced part is automatically solved when `&& arr[i] != '\n'` is added, isn't it?

Comment: @ahmet Some insight in [short-circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848858/what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-in-c) will do a lot of good. It's just a regular `for` loop that breaks as soon as a condition evaluates `false`.

Comment: @ahmet `brr[i-1] = '\0';` remains a problem.  Why would you want to remove the `char` before the `'\n'` when `arr[i] != '\n'` is true?  Further, are you assuming the buffer from `fgets()` always has a `'\n'` in it?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I meant that now that i has the correct value when it leaves the loop, I change `brr[i-1] = '\0'` to `brr[i] = '\0'`. So it no longer would try to reach `brr[i-1]` if the first element is null. On `fgets()`, well, I will always have either `\0` or `\n` by the definiton of `fgets()`, won't I?

Comment: @ahmet When `fgets()` returns non-`NULL`, the buffer will always have a `'\0'`.  It might have `'\n'` too.  It often will.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Then, I am good to go as long as I check the return by `fgets()` as you mentioned in the original answer. Thanks for all your efforts, chux and Ted.