# Logic operator AND (&&) code composer is not working

Tags: c, if-statement, microcontroller, msp430, code-composer

I'm trying to write a code in which two conditionals must be meet in order to follow the cycle, but it's not working.

```
If ((control = 10000 || control = 80000) && if((P2IN&0x02)==0)
```

If I do this, it will give me an error while debugging, but I don't where the mistake is.

Comment: `it will give me an error while debugging`:  what error when you do what? BTW trhere are 3 conditions in your code snippet and your code cannot compile, let alone be debugged...Maybe you want to [edit] and clarify.

Comment: `control = 10000 || control = 80000` -> `control == 10000 || control == 80000`

Comment: Please elaborate on what the "error" is. Is the branch taken although you do not want it to do so? Or vice-versa? Or is there some other error? Also, what is `P2IN`? If possible, please provide a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: You are also missing one closing bracket in provided code.

Comment: I guess (emphasis on "guess") you want this: `if ( (control == 10000 || control == 80000) && ((P2IN & 0x02) == 0) )`. [Edit] and write the conditions in plain english. E.g. "if  `control` is either 10000 or 80000, and if `P2IN & 0x02` is 0, then do something".

Comment: This code doesn't compile.  Please show the *actual* code you're using.

Answer (score 4):

`(control = 10000 || control = 80000)` it will always  evaluate to the `true` as

you assign the `control` with `10000` and in C language any non zero value is considered as `true`. The second part of the `||` will not be evaluated because of the [shorthand evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848858/what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-in-c)

You should read the warning as the compiler definitely has warned you about it

> If I do this, it will give me an error while debugging, but I don't
> where the mistake is.

You did not get to the debugging as this code would not compile. The second part is invalid as you do not need the second `if` (invalid syntax)

It should be `if ((control == 10000 || control == 80000) && !(P2IN & 0x02))`