# i can't understand what is happening in this c code

Tags: c

```c
int x = 10, y = 20, z = 10;
if (x == 10 || y == 20 && (z = 50))
    printf("%d", z);
```

I expected the value of `z` in output to be `50`, but it is `10`. If `&&` has higher precedence, why is `z` not assigned to `50`?

Comment: [What is short-circuit evaluation in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848858/what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-in-c) This should really have been taught by any decent book, course or tutorial.

Comment: Also related: [Operator precedence and associativity](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Since `x == 10` is true, evaluation of the expression stops at that point.  This is guaranteed by the C language.  Read about the `&&` and `||` operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the left operand for `||` is *truthy*, the RHS is not evaluated. So, the assignment to `z` never happens, and the initialised value remains.

This is called [Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: What you are saying is that `(x == 10 || the biggest nonsense)` is true :-)