# Condition in for loop not working in C if it is in certain order, swapping the orer makes it work

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop

This is happening in one of my C projects.

```
#define total 400

unsigned long values[total];
```

Initially the entire values array is initialised to 0xffffffff and then it is filled with some valid values. There is a use case where the entire array is filled with valid entries.
In that case, i see a crash and when i tried printing i value, it is going beyond total(400).

```
//Crashing, i value goes beyond 400
for (i = 0; ((values[i] != 0xffffffff) && (i < total)); i++)
{
   // some processing code
}
```

But if i just swap the condition it works fine, it doesn't go beyond total.

```
//Working fine

for (i = 0; ((i < total) && (values[i] != 0xffffffff)); i++)
{
   // some processing code
}
```

Anyone has seen this kind of behaviour. Please shed some light if you have faced this

Comment: `values[0], values[1], ... values[399]` are OK to index the 400 elements of array `values[]`.  `(values[i] != 0xffffffff) && (i < total)` eventually attempts `values[400]`.  Do you think that is OK?  What value do you think `values[400]` has as it lies outside the array `values[]`?

Comment: this is because of [short circuit evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45848858/what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-in-c). In the 2nd snippet, `i < total` fails when `i >= 400`. Since this is ANDed with something else, it doesn't bother evaluating the 2nd condition b/c `0 && x` is always 0. In the first snippet, it doesn't know yet that `i >= total`, so it accesses `values` beyond its range, invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is short-circuiting. It's intended to improve the efficiency of code.

In your first example

```
((values[i] != 0xffffffff) && (i < total))
```

the code will attempt to evaluate the first expression, and it that is `true`, evaluate the second. If the first expression is false the value of the entire condition will be false, so there's no need to evaluate the second expression.

Since you're evaluating `values[i]`, it will fail out of bounds before the bounds are checked.

Reverse the condition, as in your second example

```
((i < total) && (values[i] != 0xffffffff))
```

Now, the bounds are checked first, so the array element is not evaluated, and there is no failure.

Comment: More than efficiency, using short-circuit evaluation properly improves the safety of the code.  It's important to test for a valid index before testing the value at the index.

Comment: Re "*It's intended to improve the efficiency of code.*", Is it, though? It's common to rely on the short-circuiting behaviour of boolean operator as more than just an optimization. (This very question is about that!) It's hard to believe that was accidental.

Comment: If the condition fails, how is it incrementing i? shouldnt it stop ? i value keeps on getting incremented in this case